# specifying additional attributes on anchor tag using link_to in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Let us say I want an output html like this in rails:

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
```

How can I specify the attribues (role and tabIndex) using link_to helper in rails.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Rails docs for link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```
link_to 'Action', '#', role: 'menuitem', tabindex: -1
```

should do the trick