# How to add tabindex in link_to in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabindex

I tried to add tabindex to link to tag in my Ruby application. It's not working. How to add. I am not getting any syntax error. But on clicking tab, it is not focused. I cannot use div tag.

```
 <%= link_to xxx ,: tabindex =>1 %>
```

Comment: Syntax error? `: tabindex` to `:tabindex` Or add more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [specifying additional attributes on anchor tag using link\_to in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465783/specifying-additional-attributes-on-anchor-tag-using-link-to-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your syntax is wrong

`<%= link_to 'link text', '/link/url', tab_index: '3' %>`

from... https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Even tab_index seems not to be working. In that link also couldn't find the property